# Replacing a part of the path by another URL on haproxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I created an HAProxy to hide some API urls to the external users behind our URL (myurl.contoso.net/).

For example I have some internal API's:

| API NAME | URL | Resolved by HAProxy as |
| --- | --- | --- |
| API1 | [www.mysite.com/api/v1](http://www.mysite.com/api/v1) | myurl.contoso.net/api/v1 |
| API2 | [www.mysite2.com/api/v1](http://www.mysite2.com/api/v1) | myurl2.contoso.net/api/v1 |

I have no issues with this, because I can point these backends to the server.

And then we have another case where we use an external API but we want to convert to our URL.

| API NAME | URL | Resolved by HAProxy as |
| --- | --- | --- |
| API3 | [www.customersite.com/api/service/v1/](http://www.customersite.com/api/service/v1/) | myurl3.contoso.net/api/service/v1/ |

But I'm getting issues when I try to redirect the URL from the customer site to my url.

I'm expecting when someone make a request on postman like:
**myurl3.contoso.net**/api/service/v1/product-orders

My HAProxy rewrites into:
**www.customersite.com**/api/service/v1/product-orders

I mean, I want to convert their domain for my domain, but the rest of the request on the url should be kept.

My config:

```
frontend mysite
        mode http
        option httplog
        bind *:80
        bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/hacerts/certificate.pem
        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }


use_backend API1 if { hdr(host) -i myurl1.contoso.net }
use_backend API2 if { hdr(host) -i myurl2.contoso.net }
use_backend API3 if { hdr(host) -i myurl3.contoso.net }


backend API1
        mode http
        server node01 10.1.10.10:80 check


backend API2
        mode http
        server node01 10.1.10.20:80 check


backend API3 # (doesn't work)
        mode http
        http-request redirect location https://www.customersite.com/api/service/v1/
```